# Calculating age on a a returned date

Tags: mysql, date, math, date-arithmetic

I need work out someones age on the date that they had a procedure. I feel like i am nearly there but can someone help with this please?

```
SELECT 
p.oid,
DATE_FORMAT(p.dob, '%d/%m/%y') AS 'DOB',
p.age AS 'Current Age',
    (SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(c_vascular.OpDate, p.dob) / 365.25 AS 'Age at AVF'
    FROM
        c_vascular
    WHERE
        p.oid = c_vascular.fk_oid
            AND c_vascular.access_acc12 = '-25'
    ORDER BY OpDate ASC
    LIMIT 1)as 'Age at AVF',
(SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(c_vascular.OpDate,
                    '%d/%m/%y') AS 'AVF Date'
    FROM
        c_vascular
    WHERE
        p.oid = c_vascular.fk_oid
            AND c_vascular.OpType = '-25'
    ORDER BY OpDate ASC
    LIMIT 1) AS 'AVF Date'
FROM
person p
WHERE
p.oid IN (1234, 9876)
```

I know that the first subquery is wrong but i am unsure of how to work it out.  I think i need the "OpDate - DOB / 365.25".  Can someone help please?

Cheers guys!

Mike

Comment: DATEDIFF(day,c_vascular.OpDate,p.dob)/365.25 ??  did you try that? (although I may have the dates backwards.. I can never remember)

Comment: Just did.  I get incorrect parameter count.  I get a result with what have posted but oddly enough the persons age comes back as older than they are today!  But all the ops were performed in the last 10 years.

Comment: post exactly what you tried.

Comment: what version of SQL are you working with?

Comment: MySQL.  Just edited the code

Comment: Thats how i run it to get the data.  With the age on day of op higher than current age!

Comment: your missing the time frame parameter, it's the first parameter and should be day, dd, or d. (This is MSSQL syntax, I'm not sure on the MySQL syntax, you'll have to look it up.)

Comment: if you add a mySQL tag to your post you'll probably get more view from people who know MySQL a lot better than I do.

Comment: what formats are your dates stored in? you could try TIMESTAMPDIFF too?

Comment: Thanks - added the tag.  the format of the date is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss but i want it to display "dd/mm/yy" hence the date_format function.